# Thujohn twitter laravel Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, api, twitter, laravel-4, twitter-oauth

Trying to implement twitter authentication in laravel 4 with Thujohn Twiiter API package for laravel. The following error

```
Error in exception handler: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

keeps throwing for the line

```
$token = Twitter::getRequestToken(url('twitter/callback'));
```

in the login function I couldn't able to find why its happening.

This is my controller code below:

```
class TwitterController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */
    /*
    * user Twitter 
    */

    public function twitterlogin(){
            $sign_in_twitter = true;
            $force_login = false;

            // Make sure we make this request w/o tokens, overwrite the default values in case of login.
            Twitter::reconfig(array('token' => '', 'secret' => ''));
            $token = Twitter::getRequestToken(url('twitter/callback'));


            if (isset($token['oauth_token_secret']))
            {
                $url = Twitter::getAuthorizeURL($token, $sign_in_twitter, $force_login);

                Session::put('oauth_state', 'start');
                Session::put('oauth_request_token', $token['oauth_token']);
                Session::put('oauth_request_token_secret', $token['oauth_token_secret']);

                return Redirect::to($url);
            }

            //return Redirect::to('twitter/error');


    }

    public function twittercallback(){

        echo "test";
             if (Session::has('oauth_request_token'))
                {
                    $request_token = array(
                        'token'  => Session::get('oauth_request_token'),
                        'secret' => Session::get('oauth_request_token_secret'),
                    );

                    Twitter::reconfig($request_token);

                    $oauth_verifier = false;

                    if (Input::has('oauth_verifier'))
                    {
                        $oauth_verifier = Input::get('oauth_verifier');
                    }

                    // getAccessToken() will reset the token for you
                    $token = Twitter::getAccessToken($oauth_verifier);

                    if (!isset($token['oauth_token_secret']))
                    {
                        return Redirect::to('twitter/login')->with('flash_error', 'We could not log you in on Twitter.');
                    }

                    $credentials = Twitter::getCredentials();

                    if (is_object($credentials) && !isset($credentials->error))
                    {
                        // $credentials contains the Twitter user object with all the info about the user.
                        // Add here your own user logic, store profiles, create new users on your tables...you name it!
                        // Typically you'll want to store at least, user id, name and access tokens
                        // if you want to be able to call the API on behalf of your users.

                        // This is also the moment to log in your users if you're using Laravel's Auth class
                        // Auth::login($user) should do the trick.

                        Session::put('access_token', $token);

                        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice', 'Congrats! You\'ve successfully signed in!');
                    }

                    return Redirect::to('twitter/error')->with('flash_error', 'Crab! Something went wrong while signing you up!');
                }
        }


}
```

Routes:

```
 Route::get('twitter/login','TwitterController@twitterlogin');
 Route::get('twitter/callback','TwitterController@twittercallback');
 Route::get('twitter/error','TwitterController@twittererror');
```

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense on that code -- there are no closure's anywhere in sight, and you're not passing `Twitter::getRequestToken()`'s second argument, which takes a Closure. No clue, seems like something more is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue was with the routes. the following code fixed it.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('twitter/login',array('as' => 'twitter.login','uses' => 'TwitterController@getTwitterLogin'));


Route::get('twitter/callback', array('as' => 'twitter.callback','uses' =>'TwitterController@getTwitterCallback'));

Route::get('twitter/error', array('as' => 'twitter.error','uses' =>'TwitterController@getTwitterError'));

Route::get('twitter/logout', array('as' => 'twitter.logout','uses' =>'TwitterController@getTwitterLogout'));
```

**Controller:**

```
class TwitterController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */
    /*
    * Twitter Controller
    */
    public function getTwitterLogin(){

         // your SIGN IN WITH TWITTER  button should point to this route
        $sign_in_twitter = true;
        $force_login = false;

        // Make sure we make this request w/o tokens, overwrite the default values in case of login.
        Twitter::reconfig(array('token' => '', 'secret' => ''));
        $token = Twitter::getRequestToken(route('twitter.callback'));

        if (isset($token['oauth_token_secret']))
        {
            $url = Twitter::getAuthorizeURL($token, $sign_in_twitter, $force_login);

            Session::put('oauth_state', 'start');
            Session::put('oauth_request_token', $token['oauth_token']);
            Session::put('oauth_request_token_secret', $token['oauth_token_secret']);

            return Redirect::to($url);
        }

        return Redirect::route('twitter.error');

    }

    public function getTwitterCallback(){
        if (Session::has('oauth_request_token'))
            {
                $request_token = array(
                    'token'  => Session::get('oauth_request_token'),
                    'secret' => Session::get('oauth_request_token_secret'),
                );

                Twitter::reconfig($request_token);

                $oauth_verifier = false;

                if (Input::has('oauth_verifier'))
                {
                    $oauth_verifier = Input::get('oauth_verifier');
                }

                // getAccessToken() will reset the token for you
                $token = Twitter::getAccessToken($oauth_verifier);

                if (!isset($token['oauth_token_secret']))
                {
                    return Redirect::route('twitter.login')->with('flash_error', 'We could not log you in on Twitter.');
                }

                $credentials = Twitter::getCredentials();

                if (is_object($credentials) && !isset($credentials->error))
                {
                    // $credentials contains the Twitter user object with all the info about the user.
                    // Add here your own user logic, store profiles, create new users on your tables...you name it!
                    // Typically you'll want to store at least, user id, name and access tokens
                    // if you want to be able to call the API on behalf of your users.

                    // This is also the moment to log in your users if you're using Laravel's Auth class
                    // Auth::login($user) should do the trick.

                    Session::put('access_token', $token);

                    return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice', 'Congrats! You\'ve successfully signed in!');
                }

                return Redirect::route('twitter.error')->with('flash_error', 'Crab! Something went wrong while signing you up!');
            }
    }

    public function getTwitterError(){

    }

    public function getTwitterLogout(){
        Session::forget('access_token');
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice', 'You\'ve successfully logged out!');     
    }


}
```